# XAMPP Instalation problems with Mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have been having a lot of issues with the proper installation of XAMM for local development. The installation looks OK when completed but then I run apache and works and when I try to access the phpMyAdmin panel it says that it can't connect because of port issues.

I have seen lots of "fixes" on blogs and videos suggesting this that and the other port changes but nothing works. So I want to re-install XAMPP from scratch but I have also had other installs that use "localhost" such as WAMP and BITNAMI. I have already deleted XAMPP, BITNAMI AND WAMP. But when I look in the ***Panel de control\Programas\Programas y características ** to uninstall programs I see that I have other mysql programs in there as in this image:

[image: contol pannel >> uninstall programs]

and my question is if it is safe to uninstall these programs highlighted here so as to clean my OS and be able to re-install XAMPP without further issues of "port x is in use by..."?

I am also aware that I must erase all folder remaining of WAMP XAMPP etc in programs file.

Comment: Ryan Vincent - Thanks. Please elaborate on that. Do I go to the XAMPP website and look for "portable versions"?

Comment: maybe interesting? http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp.

Comment: Ryan Vincent - I will look into this portableapps stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Ryan Vincent - So deleting any of the above programs that begin with "MySQL... " is not going to affect anything on my operating system? In other words; are those are there because they were placed there by some developer app I downloaded?